# D j a n g o app has not valid view function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have an `app` for quiz. It shows registered quiz, but when I press submit button, It goes to `/quiz/1/do/` to `do` function in `views.py` which should do this,

```
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('quiz.views.results', args=(q.id,)))
```

But it throws an **error** message,

```
    NoReverseMatch at /quiz/1/do/

    Reverse for 'quiz.views.results' not found. 'quiz.views.results' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I wonder where could be a problem?

**Code:**

**views.py:**

```py
from quiz.models import Quiz, Question, Score
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template import RequestContext

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required()
def index(request):
    latest_quiz = Quiz.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:5]
    return render_to_response('quiz/index.html', {'latest_quiz': latest_quiz})

def detail(request, quiz_id):
    q = get_object_or_404(Quiz, pk=quiz_id)
    context = {'quiz': q}
    return render(request, 'quiz/detail.html', context)

def results(request, quiz_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the results of quiz %s." % quiz_id)

def do(request, quiz_id):
    q = get_object_or_404(Quiz, pk=quiz_id)
    try:
        answer = ''
        for question in q.question_set.all():
            answer += request.POST['q%d' % question.id]
    except (KeyError, Question.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplaying the form
        return render_to_response('quiz/detail.html', {
            'quiz': q,
            'error_message': "You didn't do the quiz %r " %request.POST,
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        s = q.score_set.create(student=request.user.username, submit_answer=answer, score=100)
        s.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('quiz.views.results', args=(q.id,))) # HERE !!!

def not_found(request, exception=None):
    response = render(request, '404.html', {})
    response.status_code = 404
    return response

def server_error(request, exception=None):
    response = render(request, '500.html', {})
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

**urls.py:**

```py
from .models import Quiz, Question, Score
from django.urls import path
from . import views as quiz_view
from . views import detail, results, do
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

app_name = 'quiz'

handler404 = 'quiz.views.not_found'
handler500 = 'quiz.views.server_error'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', quiz_view.index, name='detail'),
    path('<int:quiz_id>/', quiz_view.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:quiz_id>/results/', quiz_view.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:quiz_id>/do/', quiz_view.do, name='do'),
]
```

**models.py:**

```py
from django.db import models
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from random import shuffle

class Quiz(models.Model):
    """ Quiz model. Every quiz has 10 questions. """
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug        = models.SlugField(unique=True)
#   author      = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author')
    author      = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'quizzes'
        ordering            = ('-modified', 'created')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.title

    def options(self):
        return list('abcde')

class Question(models.Model):
    """ Question model. Each question attached to exact one quiz. """
    quiz     = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    question = models.TextField()
    answer   = models.TextField()
    choice1  = models.TextField()
    choice2  = models.TextField()
    choice3  = models.TextField()
    choice4  = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id', 'question',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.question

    def get_options(self):
        return {'answer': self.answer, 'choice1': self.choice1, 'choice2': self.choice2, 'choice3':self.choice3, 'choice4': self.choice4, }

    def randomize_options(self):
        options = ['answer', 'choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3', 'choice4', ]
        shuffle(options)
        return options

class Score(models.Model):
    """ Score model. Every quiz taken by students are recorded here. """
    quiz          = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    student       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    submit_answer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    score         = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    quiz_taken    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering  = ('quiz_taken', 'student', 'score',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %d" % (student, score)
```

It return this,

```
answer  
'a'
q   
<Quiz: Quiz object (1)>
question    
<Question: Question object (1)>
quiz_id     
1
request     
<WSGIRequest: POST '/quiz/1/do/'>
s   
<Score: Score object (4)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the line

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('quiz.views.results', args=(q.id,)))
```

to

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('quiz:results', args=(q.id,)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of reverse must be 'viewname' [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/)

> If you need to use something similar to the url template tag in your code, Django provides the following function:
>
> reverse(viewname, url conf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)

You must use view name from 'urlpattern':

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('quiz:results', args=(q.id,)))
```

Comment: #Milad Hatami thank! I was not able to figure it! I did it, but this time it shows:"Reverse for 'results' not found. 'results' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Comment: use namespace before viewname 'quiz:results'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('do', args=q.id))
```